# C kernel string concat and comparison

Tags: c, string, kernel

For reference the implementation I have of strcat and strcmp is:

```c
char *
strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    for (j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++)
        dest[i+j] = src[j];
    dest[i+j] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

int strcmp(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    while(*s1 && (*s1==*s2))
        s1++,s2++;
    return *(const unsigned char*)s1-*(const unsigned char*)s2;
}
```

I'm working on a kernel and I've tripped up on several gotchas. Basically I'm building a string like this:

```
unsigned char current_cmd[100];

    char tmp[] = {kbdus[scancode], '\0'};
    if (scancode != 0x1C) // enter key
        strcat((char*)current_cmd, tmp);
```

Then I do a comparison to see if it matches a command:

```
if (strcmp((const char*)cmd, "help") == 0)
    puts((unsigned char*)"You can't do anything yet.\n");
```

Then I do:

```
current_cmd = (unsigned char)'\0';
```

to reset it for use.

It works but I don't really understand why or how. Can anyone give me an explanation of why what I'm doing works and if there's anything wrong with my code?

Third, are `char check[10] = {"help"};` and `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', ...}` the same or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you compare with a literal? Change your code to the following:

```
unsigned char current_cmd[100];

char tmp[] = {kbdus[scancode], '\0'};
if (scancode != 0x1C) // enter key
    strcat((char*)current_cmd, tmp);

if (strcmp((const char*)cmd, "help") == 0)
    printf("You can't do anything yet.\n");

current_cmd[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: Hm, it appears you're right. I was confusing a normal comparison with `==`.

Answer (score 1):

current_cmd = (unsigned char)'\0'; is wrong, current_cmd is an array, which cannot be lvable,
you can use current_cmd[0] = '\0' instead to reset a string.

and

```
char check[10] = "help";
```

is the same as:

```
char check[10] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', '\0'};
```

but

```
char check[10] = {"help"};
```

is wrong, because it means an array of strings, not chars.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a working strcmp for you

```
int             my_strcmp(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  int           i;

  i = 0;
  while (str1[i] || str2[i])
    {
      if (str1[i] != str2[i])
        return (str1[i] - str2[i]);
      i++;
    }
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant: `while (str1[i] && str2[i])` - even so there is still a logic bug when the strings are different lengths.